# Transfer characteristic of p-channel JFET

Tags: jfet

Considering the output characteristic of the n channel JFET, can we somehow obtain the same characteristic only for the p-channel type of this transistor? [image: N channel JFET transfer characteristic]

In R.Jaeger's book about microelectronics circuit design, only a vague description was given on how only the polarities are changed, and everything else is left untouched. I suppose that means, that we will either be graphing the same curve in the first quadrant, or in the third also, only using the Vsg voltage.

Comment: I've never heard of a p channel jfet having a matching n channel equivalent. Not saying there isn't so maybe you could give an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Considering the output characteristic of the n channel JFET, can we
>   somehow obtain the same characteristic only for the p-channel type of
>   this transistor?

It's not practical because the manufacturing tolerances for any specific N channel JFET are so wide to make it a worthless exercise. See below from the 2N5486 data sheet: -

[image]

The above describes the channel resistance against temperature WHEN the voltage across gate and source is zero.

If you picked out one device that had Vgs(off) = -1V then you'd use the top curve but who knows what device you have grabbed from the handy bag of JFETs. It could easily be a device whose Vgs(off) was -8V

Because of this, Fairchild (and other suppliers) have basically created three part names for the same device because the tolerances are so wide. If you read the [data sheet](https://classes.soe.ucsc.edu/ee171/Spring04/2N5486.pdf) there are: -

- 2N5484 having a Vgs(off) between -0.3 and 3.0 volts
- 2N5485 having a Vgs(off) between -0.5 and 4.0 volts
- 2N5486 having a Vgs(off) between -2.0 and 6.0 volts

Irrespective of all that, they are still anticipating that some may have a characteristic that is -8.0 volts! It's not unknown on Fairchild data sheets to have made a typo and actually meant -6.0V.

So, trying to characterize a P ch JFET from an N ch device is fruitless

Comment: If that is so, what DOES the p-ch JFET characteristic look like?

Comment: It's a mirror image about the vertical axis i.e. the drain current is controlled by a positive gate-source voltage. The higher the voltage the lower the current. A P ch device and an N channel device are the same when Vgs is zero.

Comment: These transfer characteristics can be really helpful when doing circuit approximations, so that's why it comes in handy to have them nerby.

Comment: The problem is that reality for jfets is a wet finger in the air. When it comes down to predictability jfets are awful compared to the humble bjt as I was trying to point out.